# No space left repair

Tags: mongodb

One of the shards overflowed and crashed. Now I am trying to repair it, but it cannot repair it because no space left, see below.

```
2021-04-16T16:32:09.402+0000 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version.
2021-04-16T16:32:09.402+0000 F  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Reason: -31804: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
2021-04-16T16:32:09.402+0000 W  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Attempting to salvage WiredTiger metadata
2021-04-16T16:32:09.410+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (28) [1618590729:410858][16345:0x7f2eb9a69b00], connection: __posix_file_write, 539: /mongodb/WiredTiger.wt.orig.copy: handle-write: pwrite: failed to write 131072 bytes at offset 0: No space left on device Raw: [1618590729:410858][16345:0x7f2eb9a69b00], connection: __posix_file_write, 539: /mongodb/WiredTiger.wt.orig.copy: handle-write: pwrite: failed to write 131072 bytes at offset 0: No space left on device
2021-04-16T16:32:09.413+0000 F  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to salvage WiredTiger metadata: 28: No space left on device
2021-04-16T16:32:09.413+0000 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 50947 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 940
2021-04-16T16:32:09.413+0000 F  -        [initandlisten] \n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n
```

How can I repair a database with no disk left? I need somehow to start it that I can remove some data.

Comment: Have a log at log file folder, typically /var/log.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit It is not the log files, the data overflowed the disk, see my comment to daksh_019 's answer.

Comment: I think then you have to increase the disk. What about the secondary node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no repair with no disk space left. `repair` command is for corrupted data. So the way out is to increase the disk size somehow. Either the partition size like @daksh_019 suggested or copy data to a larger disk like I did. From there you should just launch the database and it should recover itself (if you had journal enabled, otherwise probably need `repair`).

If you do copy the files or run repair, you might need to change [the system limit of maximum open files](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/) if you are on linux.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out what is the cause of no disk space.

Often it's the log files that exhaust the disk space. If so you need to create a backup of log files and take a copy. Then remove the logs.
Logs are generally found in - /var/log unless your application is logging somewhere else.

You also need to think in terms of log rotation.

If the db itself is taking a lot of space then:

- if a snapshot policy is in place / or if its ec2 - take a snapshot of the volume.
- Increase the size of the volume and then restart the db.

Here is a link to recovery on aws: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/backup-recovery/ec2-backup.html

Not sure what you are on.

Comment: Thank for looking at this. It is not the log files, it is data, the database data on a separate dedicated disk partition (separate from logs, system files, etc.)

Comment: Hmm, few options that i can think of: 
- try increasing the disk size by snapshot route. 
- You mentioned partition - try increasing the size of the partition itself. 
- make a backup copy of the dbpath directory and use that in another machine with bigger volume.

Comment: Thanks, increasing the disk size the way to go.